# How to cancel redirection of page with click?

Tags: redirect

I have a redirection code (working fine) in several pages as follow :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content ="42; url=http://my url.html#">
```

But i want the automatic redirection to be cancelled or delayed if the user clicks in any point of the page. 
What code should i use ?
Thanks

Comment: Don't use META, use Javascript `setTimeout()`. Then add a click handler that cancels the timer.

Comment: Im using the Javascript you mentioned now (working fine).  but i don't know the code or where to put it to create the click handler.  the code i'm using now to redirect is : I'm using now a Javascript redirection code (working fine also) script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
setTimeout("location.href = 'http://www.myurl.html';",15000);
-->
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for click on page anywhere:

```
<script>
$('html').click(function () {
alert("ok"); // Do whatever you want here, just replace. Since i dont know your code. So i can help you till this point.
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm using only the META code abobe and nothing else. Would would your code be considering it ?

Comment: I don't think so that META will help u here. Best way is to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove you `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` from Documents `<head></head>`
2. Insert a simple JS-Timer and use `window.location` to refer the User after the Page loaded.

   ```js
   var timeVar = setInterval(function () {myTimer()}, 1000);
   var t = 9;
   function myTimer() {
       if (t>0) {
           document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = t;  
           t--;
        }
        else { window.location = 'what/ever/you/are/workingon.html'; }
   }

   function StopFunction() { clearInterval(timeVar); }
   ```

   ```html
   <p>Redirecting in <span id="timer" style="font-weight: bold;">10</span>Seconds.</p>
   <p onclick="StopFunction();" style="cursor: pointer; ">Cancel!</p>
   ```

The User will load your page and when not canceling the Timer be redirected to the Page you defined. If stopping the Timer the user wont be redirected and stay on the Page. br

Answer (score -1):

Try just to empty cache, it should work.

Comment: Clearing the cache will not effect a page redirect, nor will it interrupt one based on a click.  Clearing the cache is usually meant to get rid of old or corrupted data.